# firewall-cmd says no firewall zones are active. Why?

Tags: debian, firewalld

On Debian 9, I installed `firewalld` (version `0.4.4.2-1`).

`sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones` shows no output.  And `echo $?` shows the exit status was 0 (`EXIT_SUCCESS`).  Why?

I have a network interface `eth0`, which is shown by `ip link` (as well as the loopback interface `lo`).

---

I should say my firewall configuration *appears* to be mostly working.  FWIW, I have changed the default zone from `public` to `MyZone`, defined as follows:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/firewalld/zones/MyZone.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <short>My Zone</short>
  <service name="ssh"/>
  <service name="https"/>
  <!-- ... --> 
</zone>
```

If I try to connect using another computer, I am allowed to access the SSH and HTTPS services.  And if I run `ncat -l -p 8000` on the server, and try to connect with `ncat my-server 8000`, the connection is correctly blocked.  (`Ncat: No route to host.`   And `tcpdump` shows an ICMP unreachable reply is generated, type "admin prohibited").

Why is `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones` not showing MyZone as active?

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --state                                                                                                         
running
$ sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
$ echo $?
0
$ sudo firewall-cmd --get-default-zone
MyZone
$ ip addr show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:43:01:c0:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.1.8/24 brd 172.16.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd5e:fcf3:b885:0:250:43ff:fe01:c0ab/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:43ff:fe01:c0ab/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`firewalld.service` does not log any warnings.

```
$ sudo systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-01-30 13:17:31 GMT; 56min ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 509 (firewalld)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
           └─509 /usr/bin/python3 -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid

Jan 30 13:17:21 brick systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Jan 30 13:17:31 brick systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
```

---

I see that `firewalld` prefers to be used with NetworkManager.  I am not running NetworkManager at the moment, and it sounds like this is a bit fragile.

> https://firewalld.org/documentation/concepts.html
>
> If NetworkManager is not used, there are some limitations... If firewalld gets started after the network is already up, the connections and manually created interfaces are not bound to a zone.

However, I have rebooted at least once since installing `firewalld`.  I checked the `systemd` service.  `firewalld.service` is started `Before=network-pre.target`.  `networking.service` is started `After=network-pre.target`.  I have confirmed that `firewalld` is started before `networking.service`:

```
$ sudo journalctl -b -u networking -u firewalld
-- Logs begin at Sat 2019-01-26 04:15:01 GMT, end at Wed 2019-01-30 14:15:33 GMT. --
Jan 30 13:17:21 brick systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Jan 30 13:17:31 brick systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Jan 30 13:17:31 brick systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Jan 30 13:17:37 brick systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
```

I have not manually restarted networking or run `ifdown` / `ifup`, and I am not running `ifplugd`.  The kernel logs (below) say that the ethernet link has been up, and IPv6 has been running, continuously since boot.

```
$ sudo dmesg|grep eth0
[    4.082350] mv643xx_eth_port mv643xx_eth_port.0 eth0: port 0 with MAC address 00:50:43:01:c0:ab
[   47.577570] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   49.981569] mv643xx_eth_port mv643xx_eth_port.0 eth0: link up, 1000 Mb/s, full duplex, flow control disabled
[   49.991543] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

I am not even using DHCP.  The configuration for `eth0` in `/etc/network/interfaces` is

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 172.16.1.8
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 172.16.1.1
    dns-nameservers 172.16.1.1
```

Comment: Looks like what you are showing is somehow expected. `man 1 firewalld` is a bit clearer than the site you linked: "If NetworkManager is not in use [...] interfaces are not bound to the zone specified in the `ifcfg` file. The interfaces will _automatically be handled by the default zone_" (emphasis mine). Also: "You can add these interfaces to a zone with `firewall-cmd [--permanent] --zone=zone --add-interface=interface`. If there is a `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-interface` file, `firewalld` tries to change the `ZONE=zone` ... in this file." Have you tried it? (Sorry, I can't test).

Comment: @fra-san If NetworkManager is not in use *and firewalld gets started after the network is already up*.  My answer shows the relative ordering on my system...  But I think the part you emphasized is indeed the key point, and seeing this documentation makes me happier.  I've tried a manual `--add-interface=eth0`, and it then shows up correctly in `--get-active-zones`.  So I guess the Debian `firewalld` package is missing any integration for `ifupdown` (`networking.service`).

Comment: I think that "... after the network is already up, the connections ... interfaces are not bound to the zone _specified in the ifcfg_" is also a key here. Indeed the suggested command attempts to change `ifcfg` files. But what if they do not exists? It looks like `firewalld` needs zone names to be stored within an interface config (not just the other way round in zones' config) to correctly bind it to a zone. Bottom line: I agree that some integration is probably missing. Have you tested if your modified configuration survives a reboot?

Comment: This is so confusing. If it's true that unassigned interfaces will "automatically be handled by the default zone" and there are unassigned interfaces then the zone is implicitly active and firewalld should report that or at least not report ~ "no active zones ..".  And, the entire point in actually assigning an interface to a zone explicitly is just to avoid confusing messages from firewalld??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> firewalld does not depend on NetworkManager, *but the use is recommended*.

They're not kidding.

In the absence of NetworkManager, the web page document goes on to say you are required to duplicate / maintain consistency between configuration in two different places.

Additionally, the first of the two places is the `ifcfg` network configuration system, which does not exist on Debian.  By implication, NetworkManager *is* required on Debian :-).

(Synthesizing various information, it becomes clear that the duplicate configuration in `/etc/firewalld/`, is only required in case you manually start `firewalld` after the network interface has been started.  This includes if you restart `firewalld`, although you would normally prefer not to restart `firewalld`.)

On the one hand, it is probably fair to expect the specific "mostly working" behaviour which was observed in the question.  Based on other documentation and further observations, you could reasonably expect the default zone to be applied to your interface(s).

On Debian without NetworkManager, assigning an interface to a different zone will likely appear to work on the running system, but fail to work when you reboot.

You might want to have more than "reasonable expectations" for your firewall.  It is more reassuring if you can use the "recommended" configuration, which probably gets better testing when `firewalld` is changed, and not have to rely on such confusing behaviour.

And I remain confused by the implications of this, including for Red Hat systems.  It is extremely confusing that `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-interface=...` can literally shows the result "`success`", when it has failed to save the zone configuration correctly!

---

Here is the relevant quote in `man firewalld`:

> If NetworkManager is not in use and firewalld gets started after the
>          network is already up, the connections and manually created interfaces
>          are not bound to the zone specified in the ifcfg file. The interfaces
>          will automatically be handled by the default zone. firewalld will also
>          not get notified about network device renames. All this also applies to
>          interfaces that are not controlled by NetworkManager if
>          `NM_CONTROLLED=no` is set.
>
> You can add these interfaces to a zone with
>
> `firewall-cmd [--permanent] --zone=zone --add-interface=interface`
>
> If there is a
>          `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-interface` file, firewalld tries to
>          change the `ZONE=zone` setting in this file.
>
> If firewalld gets reloaded, it will restore the interface bindings that
>          were in place before reloading to keep interface bindings stable in the
>          case of NetworkManager uncontrolled interfaces. This mechanism is not
>          possible in the case of a firewalld service restart.
>
> It is essential to keep the `ZONE=` setting in the ifcfg file consistent
>          to the binding in firewalld in the case of NetworkManager uncontrolled
>          interfaces.

As an experiment, I tried the command mentioned:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=MyZone --add-interface=eth0
$ sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
MyZone:
  interfaces: eth0
```

This behaviour is what you would expect from the documentation if my network interface had been started after `firewalld`.  However my network interface was not started after `firewalld`.

The `man` page makes it sound like `firewalld` relies on getting callbacks from `ifcfg` when it starts a network interface.  However `ifcfg` is the network system for Red Hat; it is not installed on my Debian system.  It seems the Debian `firewalld` package does not provide any equivalent.  So we degrade to "the interfaces will automatically be handled by the default zone".

I ran `sudo iptables-save` to look at the iptables (IPv4-only) rules generated by `firewalld`.  If I have not manually run `firewall-cmd --add-interface...`, then there is no mention of `eth0`.  But if I read correctly, the rules handle such packets using the default zone's rules, as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not put any config files in either the `/usr/lib/firewalld/zones` or`/etc/firewalld/zones` you don't have any configured zones. All you would have is a generic firewall. Still effective depending on the rules you have, just no way to switch from public to private or any other zone you may have configured and have the rules change automatically.

Also if you used a GUI to configure the firewall, just check those directories to make sure the settings that you set actually were put in place.

If you manually put the config files there or the GUI settings manager successfully put the files for the zones you configured in place, then I have no idea.

> firewalld is a firewall management tool for Linux operating systems. It provides firewall features by acting as a front-end for the Linux kernel's netfilter framework via the iptables command, acting as an alternative to the iptables service

Check: `iptables -S`, what is there? If there are rules listed it is a generic firewall! You don't need firewalld to have a firewall you could just manually edit the iptables.

Then install `iptables-persistent`, and then save your rules after each edit with `netfilter-persistent save`

Default policy on most systems is (PUBLIC):

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Then you can elaborate with rules in the form of chains.

- Syntax:

  ```
  iptables -A INPUT/FORWARD/OUTPUT <interface> <port type> <state> <port> <what to do if match>
  ```

Example: ***(allow all incoming SSH on default port not good practice for security)***

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I disagree in the strongest possible terms.  `firewalld` is packaged with a default configuration.  `sudo firewall-cmd --get-default-zone` happens to show `MyZone` on my configuration - I customized it a bit.  By default, it would show `public`.  On Fedora Workstation, my ethernet and wifi interfaces are automatically handled using the default zone.  If `eth0` is not in a zone, what on earth is this "generic firewall" that you are talking about?  Why does it allow me to SSH in to this box - what says that SSH is allowed in the "generic firewall"?  I  doubt it is firewalled if there is no zone.

Comment: The question is about how to use `firewalld`. It is quite long already. If you have some information about why you would not expect `firewalld` to work on my system, then state it. Or other reason why I should not be using firewalld, based on my question. If you want to write your own Q & A about how to implement a firewall, feel free.  If you meet the requirements mentioned [here](https://github.com/sourcejedi/ansible-firewalld/blob/faf6139918dcf17c4eaabe09114973d566a54c4c/README.md), it will also be of interest to me.

Comment: FWIW `iptables -S` shows 61 lines. I was wrong about it not being firewalled; testing with `netcat` shows the firewall blocks ports that I have not allowed. I will edit the question.